nmake Makefile Error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
I am trying to compile a C project using a nmake makefile on Windows with Visual Studio 2019. When I run the compilation commands manually in the Developer Command Prompt, everything works fine. However, when I try to use nmake, I encounter the following error:
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'LIBCMT.lib'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

Here is the relevant part of my makefile:
# Define variables
CC = cl
CFLAGS = /MT /I include          /nologo /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS         /W4 /Od /DDEBUG
LIB = lib
LIBFLAGS = /OUT:my_library.lib /nologo
SRC_DIR = src
INCLUDE_DIR = include
LIB_NAME = my_library
OBJ = my_library.obj
TARGET = my_program.exe

# Default target
all: $(TARGET)

# Rule to compile the library source file
$(OBJ): $(SRC_DIR)\$(LIB_NAME).c
    @echo Compiling $(SRC_DIR)\$(LIB_NAME).c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c $(SRC_DIR)\$(LIB_NAME).c /Fo$(OBJ)

# Rule to create the static library
$(LIB_NAME).lib: $(OBJ)
    @echo Creating library $(LIB_NAME).lib
    $(LIB) $(LIBFLAGS) $(OBJ)

# Rule to compile the main program
$(TARGET): main.obj $(LIB_NAME).lib
    @echo Compiling and linking main.c to create $(TARGET)
    $(CC) /nologo /Fe$(TARGET) main.obj $(LIB_NAME).lib /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64"

# Rule to compile main.c
main.obj: main.c
    @echo Compiling main.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) /c main.c /Fomain.obj

# Clean up intermediate files
clean:
    @echo Cleaning up...
    del $(OBJ) $(LIB_NAME).lib main.obj $(TARGET)

Environment:
Visual Studio 2019
Windows 10
Running commands in the “Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2019”
Manual Commands:
When I run the following commands manually, they work without any issues:
cl /MT /I include /nologo /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /W4 /Od /DDEBUG /c src\my_library.c /Fomy_library.obj
lib /OUT:my_library.lib /nologo my_library.obj
cl /MT /I include /nologo /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /W4 /Od /DDEBUG /c main.c /Fomain.obj
cl /nologo /Fe my_program.exe main.obj my_library.lib /link /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\ucrt\x64" /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64"
Questions:
1.  Why does nmake fail to find LIBCMT.lib when the manual commands work perfectly?
2.  How can I ensure that nmake correctly finds and links LIBCMT.lib?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Nothing obvious.  Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see the linker searching for the file.

The problem is the use of LIB as a variable name, thereby redefining an environmental variable. Changing this to LIBB solves the problem.
